# @Assert\NotBlank not recognised

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am actually following the [Chapter 14 of the Symfony 5.0 fast track](https://symfony.com/doc/current/the-fast-track/en/14-form.html#validating-models).
I defined the Assert annotation in the use statement :

```
use Symdony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
```

And in the Comment entity: I add the *@Assert\NotBlank* for the author field which gives;

```
/**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\NotBlank
     */
    private $author;
```

- When displayin the comments page, I get the following error:

```
[Semantical Error] The annotation "@Symdony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank" in property App\Entity\Comment::$author was never imported. Did you maybe forget to add a "use" statement for this annotation?
```

- I don't understand the point as *"symfony/validator": "5.0.*",* has already been imported.
- Any Idea ?

Thanks in advance for your help...

Comment: Looks like you have a typo in Symfony namespace.

Answer (score 2):

use Symdony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;

replacing Symdony with Symfony should do it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with NelmioApiDoc bundle. What worked for me was to delete the vendor and composer.lock and reinstall all the bundles. Also you can try importing each class.

```
use Symdony\Component\Validator\Constraints\NotBlank;
```

Hope it helps. Take care

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes symfony doesnt recognize a library after an install. After installing validation lib, you need to close and open your editor.